# ¿Por qué no permite rellenar con valores el panel de Admin de Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web

Estoy utilizando el model.py de una aplicación en un nuevo model.py de otra aplicación.
Al realizar las migraciones no muestra errores y se muestra la tabla en el panel de administración de Django, no obstante no permite ser rellenada.
Ambas aplicaciones (PAppBase y Actividades) se encuentran en setttings.py del proyecto:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PAppBase',
    'Actividades',
]
```

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo:

1ª Aplicación: PAppBase   -  En models.py

```
class DiasSemana(models.Model):
    dia_semana=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='dia_semana'
        verbose_name_plural='dias_semana'
        ordering = ['pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dia_semana
```

-2ª Aplicación : Actividades  - en models.py

```
from django.db import models
from PAppBase.models import DiasSemana

# Prueba
class prueba(models.Model):
    dia_prueba=models.ForeignKey("PAppBase.DiasSemana", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dia_prueba
```

Y su correspondiente identificación en admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from PAppBase.models import *
from Actividades.models import prueba

class dia_prueba_admin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('pk','dia_prueba')
    readonly_fields=('pk','dia_prueba')
admin.site.register(prueba,dia_prueba_admin)
```

Creo que puede ayudar a entender el problema mejor la imagen añadida del panel de admin de Django. Rodeado en azul es lo único que muestra y lo que espero es un campo editable y desplegable de todos los valores de días introducidos en la App original (PAppBase):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si trato de guardar lo que se ve (el guión: "-" ) muestra este error.

```
IntegrityError at /admin/Actividades/prueba/add/
el valor nulo en la columna «dia_prueba_id» de la relación «Actividades_prueba» viola la restricción de no nulo
DETAIL:  La fila que falla contiene (2, null).
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/Actividades/prueba/add/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
el valor nulo en la columna «dia_prueba_id» de la relación «Actividades_prueba» viola la restricción de no nulo
DETAIL:  La fila que falla contiene (2, null).
Exception Location: C:\Users\ls\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 85, in _execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ls\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ls\\Documents\\Python_Scripts\\Proyectos_Django\\Pat_23\\Pat',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\Users\\ls\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 05 Jun 2022 02:16:23 +0200
```

Gracias.

Comment: He estado revisando el tema y parece que tiene que ver más con los roles de usuario ("administrador" es el que estoy utilizando) que con las ForeignKey como pensaba en un principio.
No obstante sigo buscando la solución.
Gracias

Comment: He creado un nuevo superusuario y he conseguido grabar valores de prueba pero sin poder introducir nada (no hay "celda" donde introducir los valores), es decir, solo se guarda el "pk"..... No lo entiendo.
 Se agradecen ayudas.

Comment: Sigo probando y puedo introducir valores desde el terminal, pero no desde el panel de administración de Django.
Es como si el botón "Añadir" no generase los espacios donde poder introducir los valores.

Comment: Creo que la cuestión está originada porque he customizado la aplicación de usuarios y  de login.
Esto hace que la app que aparece por defecto en el panel de administración de: "Autenticación y autorización" solo muestre la tabla de "Grupos"  -> Falta la de "Usuarios".
¿Alguien sabría cómo solucionarlo? 
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuestión de usuarios, grupos y permisos
El motivo de no ver ni poder acceder en el panel de administración se debía a no haber creado los permisos necesarios para ello.
Finalmente no quise complicarme mucho más y opté por el modelo standar de usuario de Django (originalmente lee había modificado).

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).